# How to port Tensorflow 2 model trained in python to another system running C

Tags: python, c, tensorflow2.0

I have a regression model trained in tf2, using the Python API. I would like to deploy this to a few machines running C code. It has to be C code, because I am interfacing with another software which can only read C.
Is there a way to do this?
Is there a way to do this without using the tensorflow C API? I am trying to create something for people without much/any ML experience, who only know how to use the software I am trying to interface with.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Implement a neuro-net in C and read/write the weights from your trained model in a text file? Neuro-nets themselves are fairly simple from a programmer's standpoint. Preparing the data and training the model is the hard part.

Comment: Thanks dmedine. That's what I am currently trying to do. I was wondering if there was an automatic implementation already available, like m2cgen or treelite, etc.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @TristanMüller - nothing that is an automatic implementation. Have been just writing the network by hand in C. Mine is a small network so it is not too much work to implement.